# Is it possible to create a Word Cloud with highcharter?

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

I tried it with the following code, but somehow it didn't work for me:

x4 is a dataframe, n1 a character string, and n2 the number of counts per word.

```
hchart(x4 ,"wordcloud", hcaes(name = "n1", weight = "n2"))
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, at the moment, Highcharter library doesn't have such feature, but you can always ask this question on its GitHub repository. Here is the link: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function for word cloud in highcharter, follow this code

```
data(reuters, package = "kernlab")



text = paste(
reuters[[1]])

textcld <- text %>% 
map(str_to_lower) %>% 
reduce(str_c) %>% 
str_split("\\s+") %>% 
unlist() %>% 
data_frame(word = .) %>% 
count(word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
anti_join(tidytext::stop_words)

hchart(textcld, "wordcloud", hcaes(name = word, weight = log(n)))
```

And should get something like the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pmvQ.png)

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to: 

- define custom colours for the Wordclouds
- change the brightness of the words based on the weights
  (e.g. all words in blue, but words with higher weight in dark blue and vice versa)

?

Thank you!