# Can I use highcharter and ggplot in the same Shiny App?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, word-cloud, r-highcharter

I am building a Flex Dashboard and using Highcharter to render graphs. However, I want to create a word cloud and, [from what I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211451/is-it-possible-to-create-a-word-cloud-with-highcharter), there is no way to do that with Highcharter.

If I load `library(ggwordcloud)` to create a word cloud I get error messages in all the other graphs that are built on Highcharter.

I am wondering if there's a way to use both `ggwordcloud` and Highcharter on the same Shiny app.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: As the developper of ggwordcloud, I would be interested by the error...